# Wordpress switch theme - no posts

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My problem is very strange. I have installed in Wordpress 3.5.1 two themes. One of them is this one which is default by Wordpress - Twenty Twelve. This one works fine, i mean it displays all the posts from database. Another theme which was copied from some domain, not shows any posts at all!

I also enabled debugging, but I can not see any message which would inform me about some problem with database...

Comment: We would need some code to analyze.  How is your new theme calling your posts?

Comment: Either the theme uses some custom post type, or it is using a custom query ...

Comment: Maybe maybe. When I make new post of course it does not appear. I really would like to share with you with this theme but I can not ;/

Comment: If you can't share any details we can't help you. We need more info!